# Target a specific element with no class or id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, siblings

I have a dynamic piece of HTML, which I want to target a textarea in the second FormItem div (I don't want to do this with CSS). But this textarea has no specific class or id. The HTML is as follows:

```
<h2 id="Panel" class=""><a href="#" >SEO</a></h2>
<fieldset>
    <div class="FormItem">
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="FormItem">
        <p>Some text</p>
        <textarea rows="2" cols="20" style="height: 40px;"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="FormItem">
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

And my jQuery code is:

```
$("h2#Panel").next("fieldset .FormItem:nth-child(2) textarea").css("background-color", "red");
```

But it's not working yet, what am I doing wrong?

[And my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/justamir/9e9odhxz/2/)

Comment: Please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just 
include a link to jsFiddle. Your post should stand alone from any other resource; 
consider what would happen if jsFiddle went down in the future! (It would be *terrible,* we know.)

Comment: `$("h2#Panel").next("fieldset").find(".FormItem:nth-child(2) textarea").css("background-color", "red");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.find()` in jquery in your context

```
$("h2#Panel").next("fieldset").find('.FormItem:nth-child(2) textarea').css("background-color", "red");
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9e9odhxz/3/)

Comment: This will select the text area which has id/class attribute in it. http://jsfiddle.net/9e9odhxz/5/

Answer (score 1):

Try to mix up `:not()` selector along with `attribute selector` to grab the element which has not `id` or `class` attribute in it,

```
$("h2#Panel").next("fieldset").find(".FormItem:nth-child(2) > textarea:not([id],[class])")
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9e9odhxz/4/)

Answer (score 0):

This might work -

```
$("h2#Panel").next().find("textarea").css("background-color", "red");
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ae6t0khm/)